# How to copy files to a destination, then delete the source files using a batch file/script?

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, file-copying

I'd like a batch file that can copy all files in a source folder to a destination folder, then delete *only* the source files which copied successfully. The script should overwrite any existing files at the destination.

I tried making a batch file using `xcopy` and `delete`, but the result is not what I want it to be; it deletes *all* source files even if a copy operation fails. I need any uncopied files to be left behind in the source folder.

Thanks in advance for your answer and response.

Comment: If a file already exists in your destination folder, do you want your script to overwrite that file, or skip over it?

Comment: when copying i want to overwrite the existing file on destination folder. thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I updated your question to clarify that point.

Comment: `robocopy /?` has a switch to do exactly that: `/mov`.

Comment: If you don't want to use `robocopy` (not available by default on older versions of Windows), use a `for` loop to iterate over your source files and copy them one by one, deleting the source on success: `for %%a in (*) do copy "%%a" "D:\estination\" && del "%%a" || echo failed to copy %%a`

Comment: What does the `Move` command, with its `/Y` option, not do that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: hi stephan, can you write it as script for batch file with sample source folder and destination folder? thanks

Comment: Please open a command prompt window, run `robocopy /?` and read the output help. `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "C:\Path\Source" "D:\Path\Destination" /MOV /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:3 /W:5` is all you need. No source file is deleted if it could not be copied successfully first to the destination folder.